# tf.estimator: Distributed evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

I have got a TensorFlow cluster which is able to perform distributed training of my model.
I implemented it using [tf.estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator), [tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate) together with a configured `TF_CONFIG` environment variable.

Though I am able to place the evaluation on an arbitrary machine using the `evaluator` task, the evaluation still only happens on machine.
Hence, my training is very fast since it is happening on several machines, whereas the evaluation drags behind.

Is it somehow possible to distribute the evaluation on multiple machines as it is done with the training?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: I meet same problems, have you any new updates? thanks

Comment: btw, `I am able to place the evaluation on an arbitrary machine using the evaluator task`, how could you do this? any example?
my idea is set index=0 and jobname=worker as the chief , and index=1 as the evaluator, should I update index for other workers? other workers update index as index-2, am i right?

Comment: Hi, 
Have you read the documentation of `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`?
All indeces should start from zero. So the chief obviously has `"index":0` and the workers also start with index 0. However, keep in mind that the chief is also a worker. So if you have one chief, and two workers you got three workers in total. This is especially important for your input pipeline. If you use https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shard then you have to increase all worker indeces (not the chief index) by 1. Otherwise, the chief worker and the first normal worker use the same data.

Comment: yes,it works now, thanks